# How can I retrieve the color value from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I retrieve the color value from Firebase from String to color in swift

I am a beginner, I have managed to save the color value in Firebase

But I could not retrieve it to the application

This value is in Firebase
Color: "0.424215 0.911966 0.273487 1"

This is the code that I was able to convert the color value to string and then I set it down in Firebase

```
let cgColor = self.ColorIsColor!.cgColor
                self.labelColor = CIColor(cgColor: cgColor).stringRepresentation
```

Here I want to restore color on detailLabel.textColor

```
    class CellDetiles: UITableViewCell {


var labelColor = String()

var ColorIsColor : UIColor?

@IBOutlet weak var imageLabel: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var detailLabel: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var qusLabel: UILabel!
var Dat : DetilesVC?


var arrQR : QRModel? {
    didSet {
        SetupQR()
    }
}
func SetupQR () {
    qusLabel.text = arrQR?.sub
    detailLabel.text = arrQR?.detiles
    detailLabel.textColor = ""

   
    if let stringImage = arrQR?.ImgSub {
        let image = URL(string: stringImage)
        self.imageLabel.sd_setImage(with : image)
    }
} 
}
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is split the String by spaces and separate each component out:

```
let rgba = labelColor.split(separator: " ")

let r = Double(rgba[0]) ?? 0
let g = Double(rgba[1]) ?? 0
let b = Double(rgba[2]) ?? 0
let a = Double(rgba[3]) ?? 0

let finalColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(r),
                         green: CGFloat(g),
                         blue: CGFloat(b),
                         alpha: CGFloat(a))
```

You can put this wherever you need to decode the color, but it would probably be better to put it in a `UIColor` initializer instead:

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(string: String) {
        let rgba = labelColor.split(separator: " ")

        let r = Double(rgba[0]) ?? 0
        let g = Double(rgba[1]) ?? 0
        let b = Double(rgba[2]) ?? 0
        let a = Double(rgba[3]) ?? 0

        self.init(red: CGFloat(r), green: CGFloat(g), blue: CGFloat(b), alpha: CGFloat(a))
    }
}
```

That way you can just call `UIColor(string: colorString)` whenever you need to decode it.

Answer (score 1):

How you load the color is determined by how you store it in the first place. NSData objects are quite convenient as they can be encoded, cast to a string object etc which is easily stored in firebase.

I would suggest a simple extension to NSColor

```
extension NSColor {
    func saveToFirebase() -> String {
        let data = try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self, requiringSecureCoding: false)
        let dataAsString = data.base64EncodedString()
        return dataAsString
    }
    
    func getFromFirebase(stringData: String) -> NSColor {
        let colorData = Data(base64Encoded: stringData)!
        let color = try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSColor.self, from: colorData)
        return color!
    }
}
```

then to save a color, do this

```
let red = NSColor.red
let redColorDict: [String: Any] = [
    "name": "red",
    "color_string": red.saveToFirebase()
]
colorsRef.child("red_color").setValue(redColorDict)
```

and then to read back in do this to read the red color and set the background of a view to red

```
func readColors() {
    let redRef = self.ref.child("colors").child("red_color") //self.ref points to my firebase
    redRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if let dataAsString = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "color_string").value as? String {
            self.myView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor().getFromFirebase(stringData: dataAsString).cgColor
        }
    })
}
```

Note there is NO error checking in the above for brevity so be sure to handle the optionals safely.

Also note this is macOS, but it would apply to iOS with UIColor.

Answer (score 0):

```
func getColor(_ str: String) -> UIColor? {
    let colorData = str
                        .components(separatedBy: .whitespaces)
                        .compactMap { Double($0) }
                        .compactMap { CGFloat($0) }
    
    guard colorData.count == 4 else {
        return nil
    }
    return UIColor(displayP3Red: colorData[0], green: colorData[1], blue: colorData[2], alpha: colorData[3])
}
```